# I trying to convert .apk to .jar file in cmd it shows following error

Tags: javascript, cmd, path, tools.jar, dex2jar

I tried to convert .apk file to .jar file using dex2jar in cmd and it say "java.nio.file.nosuchfileexception:"

I was expecting it to convert into .jar file

Comment: …and why do you think your problem is related to Javascript?